# Finding the list of Email-Addresses who have subscribed alerts on sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I have a list of email-addresses in a sharepoint list that send out alerts for the list whenever there is a change.

Now I face a problem to see who is on the list as I have to take away some addresses from it.

The address are from outside our domain so they are not listed in the System Administration/ User alerts.

How can I see the list or edit the list of email addresses.?

Comment: if you are not using standart alerts, as your emails are external (user alert could be only for internal users), then perhaps you are using other solution for alerting. Maybe it is a workflow, or 3rd party solution. So you need to check there first. If you know how those alert emails are sent, you will find and list of participated emails.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function get-allalerts(){
        [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
        $farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local
        foreach ($spService in $farm.Services) {
            if (!($spService -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService])) {
                continue;
            }
            foreach ($webApp in $spService.WebApplications) {
                #exclude Central Admin app
                if ($webApp -is [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAdministrationWebApplication]) { continue }
                #exclude MySite
                if ($webApp -contains "MySite" ) { break }
                foreach ($site in $webApp.Sites) {
                    foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {
                        foreach ($user in $web.SiteUsers)
                        {
                            foreach($alert in $user.Alerts)
                            {
                            $lstitemurl = ""
                                if($alert.AlertType -eq "Item")
                                {
                                $list = $alert.List
                                $lstitem = $alert.Item
                                $lstitemtitle = $lstitem.Title
                                }
                                $data = @{
                                        "WebURL" = $web.URL
                                        "User" = $user.LoginName
                                        "Alerttitle" = $alert.Title
                                        "AlertFrequency" = $alert.AlertFrequency
                                        "AlertType" = $alert.AlertType
                                        "AlertList" = $list.Title
                                        "AlertitemTitle" = $lstitemtitle
                                    }
                                    New-Object PSObject -Property $data
                            }
                        }               
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    get-allalerts | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "c:\allalerts.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

No code solution:

1. Navigate to the User Alerts section (Settings > Site Settings > User Alerts)
2. Open your browser's dev tools (usually by pressing F12)  3 3. Inspect the "Display alerts for" drop-down selector In the DOM copy the SELECT HTML block
3. Paste that into an Excel file Use the Data > Text to Columns with the appropriate delimiters to separate the names and/or emails